# Divide a integer value from map values in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a problem in Java. I have a `Map <ID, OBJ> mapState` like this

```
ID    OBJ
3     40
6     25
7     120
```

and an integer value `score=125`(for example).
I want to subtract score from `mapState's OBJ` in such way if `ID=3` have `OBJ` > score then it should subtract `125` from `mapState` value right away.where `ID=3`. But if `ID=3` have `OBJ < 125` then it will check the next value. Now I am having two values for `ID=3` and `ID=6` which is `40+25`. Again it will check if `ID3's value + ID6's value>score` `(40+25>125)` again if true then subtract it and return remaining map. Otherwise check for the next value.

For example final map returned should be, in this case

```
ID    OBJ
3     0
6     0
7     60
```

Let me know if you need more clarification on this question.

EDIT: Here is the code just cant figure it out where is the problem--

```
Set set = map.keySet();
        Iterator it= set.iterator();

        int score= 125;
        if(it.hasNext()){
            Object id=it.next();
            int val=(Integer) map.get(id);
            int finalval;
            if(val>score)
            {
                System.out.println("I");
                finalval= val-score;
                map.put(id, finalval);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("II");
                val=(Integer) map.get(id);
                id=it.next();
                val+=(Integer) map.get(id);
                System.out.println(id);
                if(val>score)
                {
                    System.out.println("III");
                    finalval=val-score;
                    map.put(id, finalval);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("IV");
                    id=it.next();
                    val+=(Integer) map.get(id);
                    System.out.println(id);
                    if(val>score)
                    {
                        System.out.println("V");
                        finalval=val-score;
                        map.put(id, finalval);
                    }


                }

            }
            System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: Where is problem? You just described algorythm you need! Just add some temporary variable to remember set of IDs to substract

Comment: Some people just enjoy down voting instead of helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got It work.

```
if(it.hasNext()){
            Object id=it.next();
            int val=(Integer) map.get(id);
            int finalval;
            if(val>score)
            {
                finalval= val-score;
                map.put(id, finalval);
            }
            else
            {
                val=(Integer) map.get(id);
                map.put(id, "0");
                id=it.next();
                val+=(Integer) map.get(id);
                if(val>score)
                {
                    finalval=val-score;
                    map.put(id, finalval);
                }
                else
                {
                    map.put(id, "0");
                    id=it.next();
                    val+=(Integer) map.get(id);
                    System.out.println(id);
                    if(val>=score)
                    {
                        finalval=val-score;
                        map.put(id, finalval);
                    }
                }

            }
            System.out.println(map);
        }
```

Comment: We can optimize it using loop for sure.